# Is this an array or not? (React)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-functions

Confused as to why this Array (?) object is not behaving like an array. I am making an API call to a cloud function, which returns an object containing an array of games. I setState this array of games, but the child component does not recognize it as an array.

> "games" does not have a length property.

Cloud function:

```
exports.getUserOwnedGames = functions.https.onCall(id => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    return steam.getUserOwnedGames(id).then(res => {
      resolve(res);
    });
  });
});
```

Client call:

```
export default class API {
  static getUserOwnedGames(id) {
    return functions
      .httpsCallable("getUserOwnedGames")("1234567890") // TEMP
      .then(result => {
        const userOwnedGames = result.data;
        return { games: userOwnedGames };
      });
  }
}
```

Parent component:

```
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      games: false
    };
  }

  loadData = () => {
    API.getUserOwnedGames("test").then(result => {
      console.log(result);
      console.log(result.games);
      this.setState({ games: result.games });
    });
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    this.loadData();
  }

  render() {
    const { games } = this.state;
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <header className="App-header">
          <GameLib games={games} />
        </header>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Child component:

```
function GameLib(games) {
  if (games.length > 0) {
    return games.map(game => {
      return (
        <div>
          <p>{game.name}</p>
        </div>
      );
    });
  } else {
    return (
      <div>
        <p>No Games! Boring</p>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

console.log(result):

```
{games: Array(32)}
```

Comment: What's the error you're getting?

Comment: games.length > 0 never resolves to true. games does not have a "length" property.

Comment: Is that the exact error you're getting? Try `Array.from(games)`.

Comment: @T_R_U_T_H check my answer and let me know if it helps.

Comment: Thank you for the help all, my API suddenly stopped working entirely... I am trying to fix it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your initial state should be an empty array

```js
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      games: []
   };
 }
```

as for child component, try this: ({games})

```js
function GameLib({ games }) { // not (games) which is props
  if (games.length > 0) {
    return games.map(game => {
      return (
        <div>
          <p>{game.name}</p>
        </div>
      );
    });
  } else {
    return (
      <div>
        <p>No Games! Boring</p>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you Kengres but that does not affect the problem.

Comment: try passing props as parameters in constructor and in super, I didn't see it before, but in React Class that's super important

Comment: see the edit of my answer. the child component was wrong

Comment: I believe you are right that I needed ({games}). I will confirm as soon as I can.

Comment: Confirmed, marked your question as the answer. Thanks for the catch!

Answer (score 2):

This is because your initial state is,

```
this.state = {
   games: false
};
```

you need to do this,

```
this.state = {
   games: []
};
```

Your component render first with default state and then your `componentDidMount` executes.

In your child component you need to do this,

```
function GameLib({games}) {
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with your 'games' state in the parent component. In the constructor you have defined 'games' as a Boolean and set it's initial value as false.

```
constructor() {
 super();
 this.state = {
  games: false // This should be games: []
 }
}
```

Set it to an empty array as mentioned above. Next problem lies with your child component.

```
function GameLib(games) // either pass props or pass {games}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your'e making an async call and initially passing an empty state Object to child component. Add loading state and when the loader resolves then load the child component. Something like this

```
this.state = {
   games: [],
   loading: true
}

loadData = () => {
    API.getUserOwnedGames("test").then(result => {
      console.log(result);
      console.log(result.games);
      this.setState({ games: result.games, loading: false });
    });
  };

 render() {
    const { games, loading } = this.state;
    if(loading){
    return(<div>Loading...</div>) 
    } else
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <header className="App-header">
          <GameLib games={games} />
        </header>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```